Joi conditional validation
I have an object which looks like this:
const preference = {
  INVENTORY: {
    id: true,
    part_name: true,
    part_number: true,
    is_available: false
  },
  ASSET: {
    name: true,
    type: true,
    make: false
  },
  DRIVERS: {
    driver_name: true,
    license_number: true,
    experience: false
  }
};

I have an update endpoint which expects a JSON which should always have a preference_type key in it which can only be INVENTORY, ASSET or DRIVERS. the rest of the keys depends on the preference_type provided.
So e.g in case of preference_type being INVENTORY the appropriate payload would be:
{
    "section": `INVENTORY`,
    "id": false,
    "part_name": false,
    "part_number": true,
    "is_available": true
}

in case of DRIVERS:
{
    "section": "DRIVERS",
    "driver_name": true,
    "license_number": false,
    "experience": false
}

and in case of ASSET
{
    "section": "ASSET",
    "name": false,
    "type": true,
    "make": false
}

How can I achieve this dynamically using the preference object?

you can try when method

For that you can use when which is like if/else.
Refer this schema
const schema = Joi.object({
    section: Joi.string().valid('INVENTORY', 'DRIVERS', 'ASSET').required()
})
    .when(Joi.object({ section: Joi.valid('INVENTORY') }).unknown(), {
        then: Joi.object({
            part_name: Joi.bool().required(),
            part_number: Joi.bool().required(),
            is_available: Joi.bool().required()
        })
    })
    .when(Joi.object({ section: Joi.valid('DRIVERS') }).unknown(), {
        then: Joi.object({
            name: Joi.bool().required(),
            type: Joi.bool().required(),
            make: Joi.bool().required()
        })
    })
    .when(Joi.object({ section: Joi.valid('ASSET') }).unknown(), {
        then: Joi.object({
            driver_name: Joi.bool().required(),
            license_number: Joi.bool().required(),
            experience: Joi.bool().required()
        })
    });


// Test
console.log(
    schema.validate(
        {
            section: 'ASSET',
            driver_name: true,
            license_number: true,
            experience: false
        },
        {
            abortEarly: false
        }
    )
);

